# Como obtengo la direccion IP y PUERTO de un esp32 en python?

Tags: python

HOLA ESTOY TRATANDO DE OBTENER LA DIRECCION IP Y PUERTO DE UN ESP32 MI OBJETIVO ES QUE AL MOMENTO QUE EL ESP32 SE CONECTE A LA RED WIFI, ESTE INMEDIATAMENTE MANDE LA IP Y PUERTO A PYTHON PARA QUE SE MUESTRE EN PYTHON, ESTOY USANDO SERVIDOR TCP

Comment: Hola. Por favor, sin mayúscula sostenida. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Por favor indica que has intentado o que código has construido, algo que nos indique que al menos lo has intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La direccion IP del ESP32 tiene que obtenerla el mismo ESP32 (lógico). Esa la obtiene el ESP32 en el momento que se conecta a la red WIFI, con un procedimiento que es básicamente igual para C++ o Python:

```
def WiFi_connect(ssid, password, host_name):
    """ Conecta a la red
        ssid: El id de la red WIFI
        password: pass del WIFI
        host_name: El nombre de host de este ESP32 (arbitrario)
    """
    station = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    station.active(True)
    station.connect(ssid, password)
    station.config(dhcp_hostname=host_name)
    print("Connecting to WiFi ...")
    while not station.isconnected():
        time.sleep(1)

    print('Connection successful: %s' % station.config('dhcp_hostname'))
    print(station.ifconfig())
```

Entonces, después de conectarse al WIFI, `station.ifconfig()` produce una lista de cuatro IP:

```
Connecting to WiFi ...
Connection successful: server.home
('172.16.0.184', '255.255.0.0', '172.16.0.1', '172.16.0.1')
```

que son:

- IP asignada al ESP32.
- Máscara de red.
- Dirección IP del router.
- Dirección IP del DNS.

La dirección IP de tu Server PC tiene que estar configurada dentro del ESP32. Una vez que ESP32 se haya conectado al WiFi, puede conectarse al servidor preprogramado.

El ESP32 también puede operar como servidor. En este caso, tienes que elegir un puerto donde escuchar las conexiones que se iniciaran desde otros equipos en la red.

¿Cómo saben los otros equipos cual es la IP del ESP32? Usando el nombre que le asignastes, no la IP (que puede variar de una conexión a otra).

Comment: y como puedo pasarle esos parámetros de manera automática a python? mi objetivo es que al momento que el esp32 obtenga la IP asignada la mane a python y que la muestre en consola, muchas gracias por apoyarme

Comment: @alexochoa. `station.ifconfig()` the devuelve una tupla de cuatro elementos con la dirección IP, la máscara, el router y el DNS, tal como se muestra en el ejemplo.

Comment: Si entiendo esa parte pero como hago para mandar la información de station.ifconfig() a python de manera automática, ya la IP cambia si el esp32 se apaga, o como puedo poner una IP para que nunca cambie?